# How to actually discard late records?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Here's the problem:

Assume a stream of numbers, I want to collect the MAX out of these numbers on 1-hour buckets, where I allow up to 3 hours of delay on a given bucket.

This sounds like a lab case for [tumbling windows](http://docs.confluent.io/3.2.0/streams/developer-guide.html#tumbling-time-windows).

Here's what I have so far:

```java
stream.aggregate(
      () -> 0L,
      (aggKey, value, aggregate) -> Math.max(value, aggregate),
      TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1L)).until(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(3L)),
      Serdes.Long(),
      "my_store"
)
```

First I cannot verify that this actually happens given a test. The timestamp is extracted via TimestampExtractor and I simulate delay with `Thread.sleep` (I set the windows to smaller values for testing), but the "late record" is still processed rather than discarded.

There seems to be little (no?) examples on regular windows. There's one integration test about SessionWindows but that's it. Am I understanding the concepts correctly?

**EDIT 2**

Sample JUnit test. Since it is rather big I'me sharing it through a Gist.

https://gist.github.com/Hartimer/6018a731753846c1930429716703e5a6

**EDIT** (adding more code)

A data point has a timestamp (of when the data was collected), a hostname of the machine that collected the data and the value.

```
{
    "collectedAt": 12314124134, // timestamp
    "hostname": "machine-1",
    "reading": 3
}
```

A custom timestamp extractor is used to fetch `collectedAt`. This is a more complete representation of my pipeline:

```java
source.map(this::fixKey) // Associates record with a key like "<timestamp>:<hostname>"
  .groupByKey(Serdes.String(), roundDataSerde)
  .aggregate(
          () -> RoundData.EMPTY_ROUND,
          (aggKey, value, aggregate) -> max(value, aggregate),
          TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1L))
                     .until(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1L)), // For testing I allow 1 second delay
          roundDataSerde,
          "entries_store"
  )
  .toStream()
  .map(this::simpleRoundDataToAggregate) // Associates record with a key like "<timestamp floored to nearest hour>"
  .groupByKey(aggregateSerde, aggregateSerde)
  .aggregate(
          () -> MyAggregate.EMPTY,
          (aggKey, value, aggregate) -> aggregate.merge(value), // I know this is not idempotent, that's a WIP
          TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1L))
                     .until(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1L)), // For testing I allow 1 second delay
          aggregateSerde,
          "result_store"
  )
  .print()
```

A snippet of the test is

```java
Instant roundId = Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS).minus(9L, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
    sendRecord("mytopic", roundId, 3);
    sendRecord("mytopic", roundId.plusMillis(15000), 2);

    log.info("Waiting a little before sending more usage. (simulating late record)");
    Thread.sleep(5000L);

    sendRecord("mytopic", roundId.plusMillis(30000), 5);

    // Assert stored value is "3".
    // It actually is 5 because the last round is accounted for
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd suspect this is more an effect of your test setup.  Could you share more of the code here?  For example, you might see the "late record" being processed but in a different time window.  Or, the way you write the input records -- which is where/when timestamps are assigned to the records -- might be incompatible with your subsequent asserts/verifications.

Comment: I edited the question to add more code @MichaelG.Noll

Comment: Thanks Hartimer.  What does `sendRecord` do exactly? Its second paramater is setting the `collectedAt` timestamp that is in the JSON payload you showed above? (I assume the JSON payload is the record value?)

Comment: @MichaelG.Noll see my own answer and related Gists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* the self-answer by Hartimer is actually incorrect.  Let me try to explain what happens, at least to my own knowledge. :-)

- Late-arriving data is handled based on time semantics that is configured for your application via the configured timestamp extractor.  In @Hartimer's case, this is **event-time** (a custom timestamp extractor is used for here).
- FWIW, in the case of **processing-time** there are, by definition, no late-arriving records: every records arrives "just in time".  A "late-arriving" record (again, there are no such records in this context) is included in the current window but never backfitted into earlier ones.
- The call `TimeWindows#until()`, which sets the retention time of a window, is a *lower bound* for the retention time.  Kafka may keep around a window for "a bit longer" (I am intentionally fuzzy here, see below) than the configured retention time.  For this reason a strict test such as the one by @Hartimer may not produce the results one might intuitively expect.

What actually happens behind the scenes with regard to the window retention time being a *lower bound* is a bit tricky (and perhaps beyond the scope of this question), so I hold off trying to explain that unless there's a specific request for me to do so.

**Update:** Also, this code in the question's snippet shouldn't even work because it should throw an `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1L))
           .until(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1L))
```

The requirement is that, for their respective input parameters, `until() >= of()`.  You are not allowed to define a window with a size of 1 hour but having a retention period of only 1 second (the retention must be >= 1 hour here).

**Update 2:** What's happening behind the scenes is that the setting of `TimeWindows#until()` is used to create/manage segment files of the local window stores.  As long as the segment of a window exists, late-arriving records for that window will be accepted.  I'll skip the part about how segments are removed/expired, because I'd really need to dig into the code for that (I don't know off the top of my head).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The unit test in the Gist shared does not throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, I believe that it is thrown if `advanceBy` is specified and `advanceBy() < of()`. I assumed the `until()` part would be the size of the window plus `until()` as the lower bound. Said test is runnable and if anyone here could check it out that would be great. It is possible I'm confusing "processing time" with "ingestion time". In any case, with the changes I mention in my answer the test works as expected, it worries me that it may do so by some other reason.. further explanation would be great

Comment: Perhaps the IAE is only thrown in the latest Kafka 0.10.2 -- perhaps you are using an earlier version?

Comment: I'm using `0.10.1.1`

Comment: Regarding your last update, I have no problem with the concept of "lower bound", I'd love some more details on the window management, let me know if I should create a separate question on that. I still need a way to reliably test "late records" and their handling...

Comment: Well, you can create a separate question, but keep in mind that what we're talking about here is internal behavior of Kafka's Streams API that you should not rely on in your code/tests.  The contract is "lower bound", and this is what you should work with (IMHO).

Comment: That's fair, thanks for the help. I believe I have enough to go on.

Comment: Cool.  If so, please don't forget to accept the answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found my own problem. It boils down to the `TimestampExtractor` and which value I was using to assess "delayed record".

In Kafka Stream terms, there are three "times" ([see here](http://docs.confluent.io/3.2.0/streams/concepts.html#time)):

- **Event-time**: When was the data recorded
- **Processing-time**: When was the data received by the stream processor
- **Ingestion-time**: (Not relevant to the question)

In my example, I was actually using the **Event-time** to determine if something was delayed, but that's not representative of a late record. Whoever collected the data will set this value to their local perception of time (in my use case at least).

The important date is **Processing-time**. How long did we take to receive the event regardless of when it was generated. My aggregation already handles grouping by "event time".

I created a new Gist with an updated version of the test that now passes. An extra field `receivedAt` was added, simulating "processing time".

https://gist.github.com/Hartimer/c79569ad517ab95d08dbe8e84bfa6789